# Unhandled exception in a text based game

Tags: c++, console, unhandled-exception

I am attempting to make a simple text based game. When the program reaches return 0, I get an unhandled exception...access violation. When I comment out the generate board and display board functions, I do not get the error. Let me know if see anything else that looks ugly.

```
class character
{
public:
    bool alive;
    bool exit;
    int row;
    int col;

    character()
    {
    alive = true;
    exit = false;
    row = 0;
    col = 0;
    }



    void receiveMove()
    {
        char a;
        cout<<"Move to the exit with w,a,s,d:";
        cin>>a;
        switch(a)
        {
        case ('w'):
            row -= 1;
            break;
        case ('a'):
            col -= 1;
            break;
        case ('s'):
            row += 1;
            break;
        case ('d'):
            col += 1;
            break;
        default:
            cout <<"Invalid Move";
        }

    }

};


class game
{


public:
    int board[10][10];



    void generateBoard()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<10; j++)
            {
                board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            int trap = rand()%99+1;
            int row = trap/9;
            int column = trap%9;
            board[row][column] = 1;

        }


        board[9][9] = 2;                                            //set last square as exit
    }


    void displayBoard(int charRow, int charCol, bool &alive, bool &exit)
    {
        ClearScreen();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
            {
                if(i == charRow && j == charCol)
                {
                cout << "X ";
                    if(board[i][j] == 1)
                    {
                        alive = false;
                    }
                    if(board[i][j] == 2)
                    {
                        exit = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                cout << board[i][j]<< " ";
                }
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }


    }

void checkForWin(bool exit)
{
    if(exit)
    {
        cout <<"You win";
    }
}

void checkForDead(bool alive)
{
    if(!alive)
    {
        cout <<"You dead";
    }
}



};



int main()
{
    character Player;
    game Game;


    Game.generateBoard();
    Game.displayBoard(Player.row,Player.col,Player.alive,Player.exit);
    while(Player.alive && !Player.exit)
    {
    Player.receiveMove();
    Game.displayBoard(Player.row,Player.col,Player.alive,Player.exit);
    }
    Game.checkForWin(Player.exit);
    Game.checkForDead(Player.alive);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your program using the debugger?  Also, you need to specify the input that you used.

Comment: It was crashing every time the game ended. No matter the input. Yes I was using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
int row = trap/9;
```

can lead to `row` being more than 9 (e.g. if trap is 90 or more), which will overflow your array. Change it to

```
int row = trap/10;
int column = trap%10;
```

Comment: Thanks. I am embarrassed I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the fragment

```
int trap = rand()%99+1;
int row = trap/9;
int column = trap%9;
board[row][column] = 1;
```

you are assigning a random value to `trap` between 1 and 99. Since in that case `row` would get the value 11, you would be out of bounds in the array `board`.

EDIT: you have to divide by 10, which is the size of your board.

Comment: Makes sense. Did you guys know to look for an array error based on the message?